# NSKeyedUnarchiver doesn't decode CLPlacemark object from CoreData data attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nskeyedarchiver

I have a core data entity with a placemark data attribute in which I'm trying to store a CLPlacemark object.

```
@interface ZJPlace : NSManagedObject
...     
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * placemark;
```

I'm encoding the object like this:

```
place.placemark = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.placemark];
```

and decoding like this:

```
self.placemark = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:place.placemark];
```

On decoding, I'm not getting an error or nil back - it just looks like an empty CLPlacemark object (`self.placemark` 's class is `CLPlaceMark` but `description` doesn't print anything to the log.)

I can see there's data saved in the `place.placemark` core data attribute but it's not getting decoded back to a proper object. It's basically the same problem as in this question: [Trouble decoding with NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3358074/2199136) which went unanswered.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here about how to use NSKeyedArchiver and CoreData together? Thanks in advance for any hints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durrr... of course there *was* something fundamental I had completely forgotten about how Core Data stores complex objects. Hope this helps some other newbie out there who's as clueless as I was. Sigh.

Docs: [Transformable attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

So here's the really simple solution to my question above about encoding a CLPlacemark in core data:

1. change type of attribute in Core Data model to be `Transformable`
2. In the header for the NSManagedObject subclass, remember to change the type of the `NSManagedObject's` property from NSData to whatever class you're trying to encode, in my case `CLPlacemark`

Then just use the attribute as you would a normal object, e.g.

```
self.placemark = place.placemark
```

No mucking around with `NSKeyedArchiver`s needed.